# Drawing a Markov chain - How do I update the value of a variable in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I would like to plot a simulation of a Markov process in R^2. Basically, I want to draw a line that starts at (x_0,y_0)=(0,2) and then follow this rule:
For each i=1,...,10, the line will go through (i,y_{i-1}+1) with probability 1/2 and (i,y_{i-1}-1) with probability 1/2. So I designed the following TikZ code to draw this figure:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
  \coordinate[label=left:$2$] (0) at (0,2){};
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\z}{2};
  \newcounter{c};
  \setcounter{c}{0};
  \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{dir}{{-1}{1}};

  \foreach \i in {1,2,...,10}{
    \pgfmathrandomitem{\d}{dir};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\z+\d};
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\i};

    \coordinate (\i) at (\x,\y){};
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\p}{\i-1};
    \draw[red] (\p)--(\i);
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\z}{\y};
  }
  \draw[dashed,thick] (\l)--(20,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

First, we draw a coordinate at (0,2). Then, we choose `\d` uniformly at random from {-1,1} and draw a coordinate at `(1,2+\d)` and we set `\z` to be `2+\d`. Then we choose `\d` again at random from {-1,1} and draw a coordinate at `(2,\z+\d)`, and so on...

However, this does not give what the picture should look like. In fact, the updating process with `\z` and `\y` does not seem to occur, and I don't know why.

Comment: Welcome to tex.SX. You can format blocks of code by indenting it 4 spaces (or highlight and pressing the [101010]-button) and inline code by surrounding it with backticks (`\``). Also, you do not need the `<br>` and `<p>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that TeX macro definitions are by default local and each loop iteration is inside a group. Hence the definition of `\z` to `\y` at the end of the loop is thrown away immediately afterwards and replaced by the original definition of `\z` as 2.

Simply replacing `\pgfmathsetmacro{\z}{\y};` by `\xdef\z{\y};` solves the problem (and is a lot faster too). The drawback of this is however that the new definition of `\z` will now globally override any macro that was stored in `\z` (if there happened to be one).

You could also replace the code by the following, which avoids any additional macro definitions:

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
  \coordinate[label=left:$2$] (0) at (0,2){};
  \pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{dir}{{-1}{1}};

  \foreach \i in {1,2,...,10}{
    \pgfmathrandomitem{\d}{dir};
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\p}{\i-1};
    \coordinate (\i) at ($(\p) + (1,\d)$) {};
    \draw[red] (\p)--(\i);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Great solution. Both approach worked perfectly well. Thanks a lot!